# Excel,Multiple Criteria Index - Match keeps returning #NA value

Tags: excel, indexing, match, array-formulas

I'm trying to find the total number of sessions on column E regarding the year,month and segment columns.
I'm using the index - match formula withing a array formula as I'm adding 3 matching criteria but I still get the #NA result.

The reason why I want to do it this way is that I'm working on some vba code and want to assign the value of that cell to a variable. Then I can use dynamic variables to iterate through each row and column as I don't know how long the list will grow.

This is the excel formula I'm using:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$E$27,MATCH(1,($A$1:$E$27=H1)*($A1:$E27=H2)*($A1:$E27=H3),0),5)
```

On the [attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGIQD.jpg) I have highlighted the row and columns that I'm using for this example, so the result would have to get the number 988860.

So my question is: How do I use the array formula with multiple criteria to find the number of  sessions?

Thanks!

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Don't use `A:E` in your match references.  Specify the correct columns.  Year is column B, so have that only be column B, Month is column A so have that be only column A, etc.  `=INDEX($E$2:$E$27,MATCH(1,($B$1:$B$27=$H$1)*($A$1:$A$27=$H$2)*($D$1:$D$27=$H$3),0),5)` and also make sure you are confirming with Ctrl+Shift+Enter for array entry.

Comment: My question is: How do I use the array formula with multiple criteria to find the number of sessions?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you tigeravatar,I changed the formula to look each criteria on its specific column and it works!
So the final formula looks like this:

```
={INDEX($E$2:$E$27,MATCH(1,($B$1:$B$27=$H$1)*($A$1:$A$27=$H$2‌​)*($D$1:$D$27=$H$3),‌​0),5)}
```